# C++ std::shared_ptr would initialized other member data in the class

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization

My question is:
When I introduce the `std::shared_ptr` into class B, it would give other data member the zero-initialization.

The code is given below:

```
class A
{
    public:  
        int data_a;  
        A():data_a(0){}  
    };

    class B 
    {
    public:
        int data_b;
        A a; 
        //shared_ptr<B> ptr_b; // the key point here
    };

    int main()
    {
        B b;
        cout << b.data_b << endl;
    }
}
```

As member `a` has a default ctor so B would generated an implicit default ctor.
Now I didn't introduce the `shared_ptr` so the output would be:

```
-858993460
```

But once I introduced the `share_ptr` into the codes, the output became:

```
0
```

Why? What makes this happen?

Thanks in advance.

*I am using microsoft blend for VS community 2015 version 14.025425.01 update 3.*

Comment: Accessing `b.data_b` exhibits undefined behavior. [Any outcome whatsoever](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) is valid.

Comment: Thanks. I know this point. But I wonder what makes it generate a zero-initialization when I introduce the shared_ptr `prt_b` into class B? you see, the result was 0 when I made such a change.

Comment: Your code has a bug. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. If your question is "Why does code with a bug do strange things", it's because that's the nature of bugs.

Comment: If you know that undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour, why do you still ask why this happens? It can happen for any reason, but because it has no meaning whatsoever since one must not rely on undefined behaviour it's pointless to try to find a reason.

Comment: oops, maybe right now I know what is the meaning of **undefined behavior** Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit-default constructor will default-initialize your scalar data members, so they will have an indeterminate value. As for your test case, it has undefined behavior as you're trying to print an uninitialized object. Any output whatsoever is valid.

Comment: @J.Wei Like I said, it's undefined behavior. You can't makes sense of the  output because what you've done is not valid. There's nothing in the language that is supposed to make a `shared_ptr` cause zero-initialization of the data members. It's just an effect of undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, I got it. You solved my puzzle. It is my misunderstanding for the meaning of undefined behavior. Thanks a lot!!!!